# My prefabs' size appears wrong when placed

Tags: unity-game-engine

So on a game I am working on, I keep having the same problem where whenever I turn an object into a prefab, somehow the object always appears smaller but the width and height says otherwise. I can't seem to fix this problem and it also applies whenever I try to instantiate it, it always remains that way even when I just create a prefab.

[The Prefab as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4n53.png)
The image I screenshot shows what happens whenever I assign or make an object as a prefab. Am I doing something stupid? or is it just because there is a setting I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

In unity ths scale of an object affected by it's parent scale..
so for example if I have a cube with width 10 unit and it is scale is [10,1,1]
and I convert it to prefab every time Iniciate object from it will be in the same scale..
the problem apper if my cube was a chiled for other game object with scale for example [5,5,5]...
as you see in this picture
this is the same prefab but the size is totaly diffrent because of the parent
[image]

to avoid this proble be sure always to make your prefab with scale 1 1 1
you can create an empty game object with scale 1 1 1 and position[0,0,0] then make your object child of it then make your prefab  ...

:) and if you want further help pleace give more specific informations for your problem

Comment: Hi, so I did just as you said and made sure that the scale of the prefab is [1,1,1] and I also did what you said about the empty game object with scale [0, 0, 0] and position [0,0,0] but the object isn't visible instead and still shows the wrong size although it says in the inspector that it's scale is [1 ,1, 1].

Comment: I apologize I was writing fast and type it wrong I was mean scale for [1,1,1]..

Comment: So I did just that but the object size still shows up wrong I actually tried placing a box collider on the object before turning it into a prefab to see what's really going on since I can't see it. It actually shows that the prefab that was placed on the scene for some reason takes up about one fourth of the scene but the actual object is almost microscopic or it has completely disappeared but the hierarchy says that it is still there.